# Get first day of current and next month in VBSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript

I can find first day of current and next month using SQL Server 2008 
Thare is my code:

```
   declare @date_begin date= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
   declare @date_end date= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@date_begin))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,@date_begin)),101)
   select @date_begin, @date_end
```

It return me:

```
    2013-12-01  2014-01-01
```

But now I need to get first day of current and next month using VBScript. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do same thing using DateSerial in VBScript.
From [Remarks Section - DateSerial Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> To specify a date, such as December 31, 1991, the range of numbers for
>   each DateSerial argument should be in the accepted range for the unit;
>   that is, 1–31 for days and 1–12 for months.
>
> **However, you can also
>   specify relative dates for each argument using any numeric expression
>   that represents some number of days, months, or years before or after
>   a certain date.**

So, all you need is specifying year, month and day values.

```vb
Function CustomDate(dtm)
    Dim y, m, d, h, n, s
        y = Year(dtm)
        m = Right("0" & Month(dtm), 2)
        d = Right("0" & Day(dtm), 2)
        h = Right("0" & Hour(dtm), 2)
        n = Right("0" & Minute(dtm), 2)
        s = Right("0" & Second(dtm), 2)
    CustomDate = y & "-" & m & "-" & d
    If h + n + s > 0 Then
        CustomDate = CustomDate & " "
        CustomDate = CustomDate & h & ":" & n & ":" & s
    End If
End Function

WScript.Echo "1st day of current month", CustomDate(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1))
WScript.Echo "1st day of next month", CustomDate(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1))
```

Comment: But I have one more question. I need date in format 2013-12-01. Your code return  #12/1/2013#. Can You halp me ?

Comment: @Oleh When you evaluate a date variable as string it will be formatted in current locale. I'm getting same date formatted in Turkey's as `1.12.2013`. Well, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Oleh `DateSerial` returns a value of type `Date`. If you need an ISO formatted date string you need to build it yourself. Search for `[vbscript] date format`.